# TWTRTweetView don't show all image

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter

Im using TWTRTweetView to show tweet in my ios app. but there is a problem the TWTRTweetView don't show all image. It only show one images. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I just found the thread and Twitter itself is not providing this feature according to this thread. https://twittercommunity.com/t/twtrtweetview-not-showing-all-images-in-ios-swift-tableview/57938

Comment: yes, i see it but its from 2015 :(

Comment: Yes i see too. and you can post there for faster response. :)